# Why there is no new UwpDesktop package version released for new windows kit UAP Version

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge, uap

> We have new window kit platform UAP version 10.0.15063. But I dont see
>   UwpDesktop package Version for this UAP version.

I found new version of UAP on my windows 10 machine.

And when I go for its UWPDesktop package version then I do not gets its package version.

Here is link for UwpDesktop nuget packages versions :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop

Answer (score 1):

We are working on the package and should get an update out soon. In the meantime to get unblocked you can add the references to the 15063 SDK manually as described in this blog post:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application